# Vue-i18n loader webpack config with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel-mix, webpack-5, vue-i18n

We have a project setup with Laravel and Mix, Vue (2.7) and Vue-i18n which was working up to now. We recently had to ugprade to Mix 6 and Webpack 5 in order to install TailwindCSS and the Vue-i18n loader is no longer working.

Here's my config:
`webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.extend( 'i18n', new class {
    webpackRules() {
        return [{
            resourceQuery: /blockType=i18n/,
            type: 'javascript/auto',
            loader: '@intlify/vue-i18n-loader',
        }];
    }
}());

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
    .options({
        postCss: [
            require("tailwindcss"),
        ]
    })
    .i18n();
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.5.0",
        "browserslist": "^4.8.7",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001030",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.6.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.19",
        "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.13",
        "sass-loader": "^11.1.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
        "vue": "^2.7.14",
        "vue-bootstrap-typeahead": "^0.2.6",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.15.3",
        "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
        "vuex": "^3.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
    },
    "main": "tailwind.config.js"
}
```

The error I'm getting now is:
`Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`

in every file where I'm referencing vue-i18n

Comment: Did you update vue-i18n ? the current version you have might not be compatible with webpack 5. You might be out of luck because it seems vue-i18n 9 is only for vue 3, and vue-i18n 8 only works with webpack 4 according to the package.json

Comment: Upgrading to webpack 5 but staying on vue 2 might prove challenging with some packages

Comment: @Lk77 yeah the original package is abandoned, I switched to another which seems to be a fork of the original. They say it's compatible with vue2, the dep installed. Do you know if webpack 4 might be a better fit ?

Comment: the package is not abandoned, it was moved over intlify organisation, but the maintainers are the same, see : https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/769 . Webpack 5 is better, but if you plan to stay on vue 2 it will be harder i think, perhaps not worth it, also tailwindcss@2 works with webpack 4, you might want to try it before upgrading webpack